# Facebook App Insights Added App versus User Accepts

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

On the INSIGHTS->User Tab.  The chart called "User Trends" shows "Added App".

I believe this means they 'saw the install dialogue', or 're-added an app they may have previously uninstalled'.

If you look at the "Growth" tab under User.
To me it is quite clearly new user accepting the auth dialogue (which is what creates users).

Why would these numbers be different?  (usually Growth->Accepted Auth Dialogue is smaller #).

Also generally, is there a guide to Insights somewhere?  I've looked all over and can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some docs from Facebook on Insights:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/554/